# WPF - Style - Binding to self property in GridView header

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview, width

I think this is a simple task, but I couldn't figure out how to do it, neither found the solution. I have a simple wpf app, where I have a listview with a gridview view. I am doing a simple restyling to the columnheader:

```
    <ListView Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Reservations}" Name="MainListView">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Padding="5,0" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>

                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{Binding Path=Content.ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
                <!-- Columns -->
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

This styling aligns the header texts to left with a 4px indentation from left.

Now what I wanna achieve is that the minwidth property of each column gets set according to ActualWidth property of the textblock in the header. I have tried to accomplish that using this piece of code from the style

```
<Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{Binding Path=Content.ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

But as expected, it doesn't work. How to do the binding the right way?

Comment: Chnage the MinWidth value binding to this: `{Binding Path=Content.ActualWidth, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`. Then watch the VS Output pane at runtime. Money shot: *BindingExpression path error: 'ActualWidth' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-838420505)'.*

Comment: You see, `Content` is the value represented by `{Binding}` in the `ContentTemplate`. It's a string, the title of the column. The trouble is that the binding needs to be at the parent level, and there's no "FindDescendant" mode for Binding. You could do this with an attached property/behavior.

Comment: I just tested this. Try setting a constant MinWidth on GridViewColumnHeader: It determines the width it starts at, but the user can still change it with the mouse. I think this may not be possible.

Answer (score -1):

TextBlock element isn't an ancestor of GridViewColumnHeader. Therefore an possible way can be to add an Converter to binding.

```
<Setter 
    Property="MinWidth" 
    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={x:Static local:MyGridViewColumnHeaderConverter}}" 
    />
```

Inside MyGridViewColumnHeaderConverter there can be looked for children by VisualTreeHelper and returned ActualWidth of founded TextBlock.

Comment: I think you didn't even glance at this after submitting it, because the code was invisible due to being formatted wrong. I fixed it for you.

Comment: Strangely enough, it actually was visible for me... I was checking it for about 20 min after publishing, but since no response was showing up yet, I came back just now. Thx